# Is it possible to change a word using regexp_replace() function?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to change the State_Name to California using regexp_replace()?

```
select  REGEXP_replace("Name,Door_No,Street_Name,Area_Name,State_Name,12345", r"","California") AS example
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the many options -

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
  "Name,Door_No,Street_Name,Area_Name,State_Name,12345", 
  r"([^,]*,)([^,]*,)([^,]*,)([^,]*,)([^,]*)(,[^,]*)", 
  r"\1\2\3\4California\6"
) AS example
```

returns

```sql
Row example  
1   Name,Door_No,Street_Name,Area_Name,California,12345
```